# Responsive testing, strange css behavior

Tags: css, positioning

I have a strange problem with responsive testing on a project that I am working on. When I test it (like I always do) in chrome developer tools it looks all messed up, but on phone it's good and vice versa.

Example:

Try this on chrome developer tools and put iphone 5 as a test device:
http://www.vinarijapantic.com/apps/onePage/, and you will see all kind of bad positioning. When tested on a real iphone 5 it's all good. I founded this emulator to be "real" so I use for now

http://iphone5simulator.com/ but I can't figure out why chrome developer tools and safari developer tools are showing bad positioning. What I see is not what I get on a real device. Never had this kind of problem before.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just tried the first link with the iphone5 emulator on my Chrome 47.0.2526.106/Mac OsX and all seems fine. What should be messed there?

Comment: Tried your link on Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m on Windows 8.1 with iPhone 5 emulation and it seems to be fine. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Can also confirm, looks fine. Try disable cache in the network tab?

Comment: You guys get same results when you test on your chrome developer tools and iphone5ssimulator site? Any screenshots of chrome developer tools? showing the first slide (logo) if it isn't too much trouble for you?

Comment: Check the logo positioning, as a reference point. It should be under white line.

Comment: I do NOT get the same results between the two. For example, scrolling down to the "About Us" overlay, it's in a different position in chrome using iPhone5 in developer tools than it is in the iPhone 5 simulator.
EDIT: upon further inspection you appear to have some odd media queries in there. When I adjust the viewport width, the whole page bounces as if to reset.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am talking about, it simply isn't the same. And when you test it on a real iphone5 its equal to iphone5ssimulator. Chrome dev tools are showing wrong positioning. Same for and roid devices, lets say galaxy s4. It might have something to do with the javascript library (fullpage.js), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

hello dear to check responsive design or issues i found some tools website,
you may test here, may be it will help you as like me.

http://responsivetesttool.com/

http://ami.responsivedesign.is/

even local server address using local IP also work here. if any site works here correctly then it will work in live on any device. May be it could be helpful to you.